# Install EMMS and missing executable (emms-print-metadata)

Tags: emms

**Q:** how do I populate the cache in EMMS?

I just did a fresh install from source of Emacs, and then got the
`emms` package from melpa.  When I go to populate the EMMS cache,
I get the following error message:

```
Error running timer ‘later-do-timer’: (file-missing "Searching for program" "No such file or directory" "emms-print-metadata")
```

I've gotten this message in the past, and it's always puzzled me.
What is this executable (`emms-print-metadata`), where do I get it, and how do I install
it?

I'm pretty sure I can get emms as a `.deb` package and install it
through my distro's package manager, but that's not the point.
I'd like to install EMMS through the *Emacs* package manager.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`emms-print-metadata` is a C shim to enable use of `libtag` for extracting metadata from music files.

It should only be needed if you have done something like

```
(require 'emms-info-libtag)
(setq emms-info-functions '(emms-info-libtag))
```

in yr config.  See the [EMMS manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/emms/manual/#Using-TagLib) for more information.

If `libtag` is installed on yr system and you want to use it, you need to get the emms source:

```
git clone https://git.savannah.gnu.org/git/emms.git
```

There you will find the C source of `emms-print-metadata` and a makefile.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Right you are; I put the `emms-info-libtag` part in my init file years ago and forgot all about it.  It surprises me that there's an executable involved, but so it goes.